# Add transparent rectangle to spplot

Tags: r, lattice, r-sp

Reproducible example (fig01 from [rspatial](http://rspatial.r-forge.r-project.org/gallery/)):

```
library(sp)
library(lattice)

data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse)=~x+y
spplot(meuse, "zinc", do.log = TRUE,
       key.space=list(x=0.2,y=0.9,corner=c(0,1)),
       scales=list(draw=T))
```

Now, I would like to make the same plot with a transparent rectangle which boundaries are specified in terms of the "native" units of the data coordinates (different from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48218206/597069) answer):

```
spplot(meuse, "zinc", do.log = TRUE,
       key.space=list(x=0.2,y=0.9,corner=c(0,1)),
       scales=list(draw=T),
       panel=function(){
         panel.rect(xleft=180000, ybottom=330000,
                    xright=181000, ytop=330500, alpha=1)
       })
```

However, I end up with a new plot without the data points:

[image: fig01_with_panelrect]

Answer (score 2):

Inside the panel function, one should also call `panel.points` at the end so that data points are drawn after the rectangle:

```
spplot(meuse, "zinc", do.log = TRUE,
       key.space=list(x=0.2,y=0.9,corner=c(0,1)),
       scales=list(draw=T),
       panel=function(x, y, ...){
         panel.rect(xleft=180000, ybottom=330000,
                    xright=181000, ytop=330500, alpha=1)
         panel.points(x, y, ...)
       })
```

[image: fig01_with_panelrect_and_panelpoints]